# App not installed error while sideloading and Install failed UID changed via adb [Not rooted]

Tags: applications, adb, side-loading

I am having hard time getting an app installed since none sideloading nor adb install work...since I dont have root i cant delete the app's data folder from the data/data folder..

seems delete that folder will easily fix it but I am wondering is there any other way.

Error via adb install  is **Install failed UID changed**
I dont wanna root is there any fix for this.....

BTW my phone is Moto g

Answer (score 0):

For rooted devices:

Run the below command

```
adb rm -rf /data/data/<your.package.name>
```

For non-rooted device:

1. Change the ApplicationId of the app. Refer this [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) to change
   ApplicationId.
2. Build and install the app. App will install successfully because it is treated as new app.
3. Now uninstall this app. Which will clear the data.
4. Now change the ApplicationId to the previous one.
5. Build and install. Magic.. It will install.